# How can I use Powershell to add a site to my IIS or IISExpress server

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-express

Is it possible to add a site (and bindings) to my `applicationHost.config` file for IIS Express or IIS ?

here's one I had to manually add (which works perfectly) ...

```
<site name="Our Awesome website" id="4">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\XWing\Code\Application\Website" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1200:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost.www.mywebsite.com.au" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44302:localhost.www.mywebsite.com.au" />
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost.www.mywebsite2.com" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44302:localhost.www.mywebsite2.com" />
```

/>

Is this possible? (i'm assuming the `<site>..</site>` does ***not*** exist)

Comment: To the person who thinks this is not relevant to prof ITOps, please suggest another SE sister site, instead of just downvoting. please :)

Comment: Here's how I did it
http://stanbashtavenko.com/managing-iisexpress-with-powershell/
There is a link to complete script at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New-Website and New-WebBinding[2] applets should do what you are asking.

---

1: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790605.aspx
 2: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790567.aspx

Comment: Can I use these to *check* if a website exists (eg. -> if "Our Awesome website" doesn't exist .. then `New-Website`....)

Comment: You would use Get-Website applet

Comment: And finally - two more questions please :) 1) Can this be used against the *IIS express* (not just IIS) .. and 2) if the site doesn't exist, `Get-Website` throws an error message? how to avoid the error? (basically, i'm trying to do -> `$result = Get-Website -Name "Our Awesome website"; if (-Not $result) { add .. } else { .. do nothing }`

Comment: I don't know from IIS Express, so I couldn't tell you. You could make $results an array and suck in all of the entries in Get-WebSite. Then <code>if ($results -contains "Our Awesome website) {Write-Output "Found it"} else { Do-TheNeedful -onceMore -withFeeling } </code>